# Accessing QT combo and textbox values

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

I'm using Python 3  and QT4 with pyqt. I've been unable to access data from qcomboboxes and qplaintextedits.

I've read the documentation here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html

The only thing on these pages that appears to describe how to pull the selected value are 'plainText' for the plain text box and 'currentText'for the combo box. These aren't explicitly described as the solution, but they're the only thing I found that makes sense.

currentText returns the following error: "AttributeError: 'QPlainTextEdit' object has no attribute 'plainText' "

currentText does not return an error, but returns the starting value of the combo box, regardless of what's selected.

Example code I'm using:

```
x = window.ui.tb_x.plainText()
y = window.ui.cb_y.currentText()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Its toPlainText() method in qplaintextedit.

And try itemData( combo.currentIndex ) for combo.

Comment: Thank you - these items are accepted with no errors, but have similar effects: The textboxes return 'None', and the comboboxes return their default value. I have 0 idea what's causing them to do this, as it should be a simple operation. I'm using Designer to create the UI, and have the code in the main part of my program. Learning QT seems to be more of a challenge than python itself!